# How to change Ethereum default directory

Tags: go-ethereum

Im trying to run `geth attach` on my console , i have already started a node , this is the script that i used :

```
    #!/bin/bash

geth --identity "miner1" --networkid 42 --datadir "~/Desktop/Tutorials/ChainSkills/miner1" --nodiscover --mine --rpc --rpcport "8042" --port "30303" --unlock 0 --password ~/Desktop/Tutorials/ChainSkills/miner1/password.sec --ipcpath "~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc" --allow-insecure-unlock
```

And this is the log that i get : [image: Log]

Now when i run `geth attach`
i get this error :

> Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix
>   /home/louay/.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory

I think that i should change the Ethereum default location because `geth.ipc` is in other directory not the one mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try

`geth attach ~/Desktop/Tutorials/ChainSkills/miner1/geth.ipc` ?